# Apache mod_rewrite ignore some real directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

That's my root directory:

```
css
img
js
includes
templates
api
```

and that's my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?ur=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works fine but when I inform the url a directory exists, the Apache open the directory, when in fact it should inform the URI for **ur** parameter.

For example:
**mydomain.com/test-uri/** goes to **ur** parameter.
**mydomain.com/api/** apache loads the **api** directory.

I did some research, but the most we got was to consider all directories when I need only pass the **api** directory as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-d` check:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?ur=$1 [L,QSA]
```